# Docusign SOAP PHP API breaks with Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: docusignapi

I downloaded the [DocuSign API](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-SOAP-SDK) and input my credentials, but when running an example, the API client dies because of class redeclarations.

It seems like the PHP API is just broken... but I see no similar questions about it on SO.

I commented out a bunch of declarations to get it to run. Has anyone else experienced this or know anything about it?

[APIService.php](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-SOAP-SDK/blob/master/PHP/CodeSnippets/api/APIService.php)

```
class EnvelopeEventStatusCode {
  const Sent = 'Sent';
  const Delivered = 'Delivered';
  const Completed = 'Completed';
  const Declined = 'Declined';
  const Voided = 'Voided';
}

class EnvelopeEventStatusCode {
  const Sent = 'Sent';
  const Delivered = 'Delivered';
  const Completed = 'Completed';
  const Declined = 'Declined';
  const AutoResponded = 'AutoResponded';
  const AuthenticationFailed = 'AuthenticationFailed';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the code snippets. Do Use DocuSign Sample folder files instead and open Index.php to test it out.

It happens to me when I was developing.

Comment: Wow, you're right. They have duplicates of their API code in both folders and the one in CodeSnippets is broken.The example in DocuSignSample runs, but sending a document breaks with " Validation error: The element 'Documents' in namespace 'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0' has incomplete content.".

Comment: Did you fill in the email? it shouldn't be blank else it will break.

Comment: I did. I'll open a new question for that issue. Thanks for your help.